# Issue in python Hive connectivity

Tags: python, hive, database-connection, connectivity

I am trying to connect the python with Hive, and I am getting following message on terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "eg.py", line 18, in <module>
database='default')
```

`File "/home/ashok/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhs2/__init__.py", line 6, in connect`
    `from .connections import Connection`

```
File "/home/ashok/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhs2/connections.py", line 7, in <module>
from cloudera.thrift_sasl import TSaslClientTransport
ImportError: No module named cloudera.thrift_sasl
```

Even after doing some google work, I can't find the answer.
Help me out here.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? How?

Comment: Please will write text your code